# how to convert a column contaiting lists of nested dictionaries into dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column that has lists of dictionaries:

[image]

The dictionaries have three things, createdBy , CreatedAt, Notes of different candidates. I need to get them in separate columns. I need to open this candidatesNotes into three columns that is inside dictionary. I have tried the following but this is creating 6 columns

[image]. I need only 3. The nested candidateNotes column looks like this:

[image]. There is data and time in the candidatenotes dictionary, using time and date for each candidate id(that is in separate column) I need to update the status in separate columns, may be looking like this:

[image]

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df1['candidateNotes']).add_prefix('s')
df2 = df2.s1.apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('') \
.merge(df2, left_index = True, right_index = True)
df2 = df2.s0.apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('') \
.merge(df2, left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

here is the error screenshot @qaiser :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pandas has a method for this type of issues, namely `json_normalize`. You can see the detail [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)

Comment: Just iterate through the dataframe, get that column value and do pd.DataFrame(). Append all individual dataframe to a main dataframe (initially empty).

Comment: it shows there are no keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 

#creating dataframe which contain dictionary as row 
cf = pd.DataFrame([[[{'createdat':'abc','createdby':'asas','createdon':'lklj'}]],[[{'createdat':'aaaaa','createdby':'asas','createdon':'lklj'}]]]) 


df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(cf.shape[0]):
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([cf[0][i][0]]), ignore_index = True)
```

[image]

```
cf = pd.DataFrame([[[{ "createdAt": "2019-07-09T21:47:59.748Z", "notes": "Candidate initial submission.", "createdBy": "Akash D" }]],[[ { "createdAt": "2019-07-09T21:47:59.748Z", "note": "Candidate initial submission.", "createdBy": "Akash D","demo":"abc" } ]]], columns=['CandidateNotes']) 

print(cf)
```

[image]

```
 df = pd.DataFrame()
 for i in range(cf.shape[0]):
     try:
        df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([cf['CandidateNotes'][i][0]]), ignore_index = True)
     except:
        print(i)
 df
```

[image]

Comment: there are more than 50000 in this column "candidateNote" .  applying yours, i am getting key error 0.

Comment: but this i got for first row, there are nested dictionaries . i am not getting all dictionaries in separate columns

Comment: in image shared by you nested dictionaries are not visible, can you provide the nested dictionary with expected output...

Comment: now u look, i hv uploaded, i have 2 columns , "id" and "candidateNotes". for each id there are notes that has timestamps and the staus. also person who has updated the status. so i need all the status in separate columns according to timestamp. please help me with this.

Comment: can u send me your email id?

Comment: i asked how nested dictionary look, but in the image in Candidates Notes only timestamp is visible after that no... is there which i am not able to understand.  make a sample data with nested dictionaries post that ...

Comment: "candidateNotes": [
          {
            "createdAt": "2019-07-09T21:47:59.748Z",
            "notes": "Candidate initial submission.",
            "createdBy": "Akash D"
          }
        ],

Comment: its a json file of more than 1000 ids and has 150 columns

Comment: it is working Aamer, i have also added key like demo, change the note to 'notes', it is working fine. if key is not there in other record value will become nan.

Comment: its not working. i am uploading the key error screenshot.

Comment: it works only for first dictionary of the list of nested dictionaries of the column

Comment: i hv uploaded the error that i am facing, also u can see the dataframe above it.

Comment: use try and except, and check whether you are getting error for all record or for some record.i have modified that in the code.  which version of pandas you are using

Comment: its only splitting first dicitionary for every id. So, i am still getting only first. but i am using different methods now.